# perl6 grep like program in parallel

Tags: concurrency, raku

I wrote a grep-like program in perl6, and now I made it into parallel processing. But I ran into some problem: even with the same command line the program sometimes succeeds, and sometimes fails. When it succeeds, things looks just normal to me. When it fails, I don't know why...

Here is the error message when it fails.

```
> grep6 perl *
An operation first awaited:
in sub MAIN at /Users/xxx/Dropbox/bin/grep6 line 28
in block <unit> at /Users/xxx/Dropbox/bin/grep6 line 30

Died with the exception:
Cannot find method 'Any' on object of type Match
  in regex  at /Users/xxx/Dropbox/bin/grep6 line 34
  in sub do_something at /Users/xxx/Dropbox/bin/grep6 line 34
  in block  at /Users/xxx/Dropbox/bin/grep6 line 24
```

And the code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6  

constant $color_red = "\e[31m";
constant $color_off = "\e[0m";

sub MAIN(Str $pattern, *@filenames){
    my $channel = Channel.new();
    $channel.send($_) for @filenames; # dir();
    $channel.close;
    my @workers;
    for 1..3 -> $n {
        push @workers, start {
            while (my $file = $channel.poll) {
                do_something($pattern, $file);
            }
        } 
    }
    await(@workers);
}

sub do_something(Str $pattern, Str $filename) {
    #say $filename;
    for $filename.IO.lines -> $line  {
        my Str $temp = $line;
        if $temp ~~ s:g/ (<$pattern>) /$color_red$0$color_off/ { 
            say $filename ~ ": " ~ $temp;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is why it fails sometimes?

Regards

Xin

Comment: I would say you're closing the channel before there's any time to read from it. If there's a small delay in closing it, there might be some time for the workers to start, but in general that will not happen. You shouldn't close the channel until there's nothing else there, that is, untill all workers have finished.

Comment: perl6 -e 'my $channel = Channel.new;$channel.send("Hi");$channel.close;my @w;for ^3 { push @w, start { say "Reading";while my $data = $channel.poll { say $data }; say "Done" } };await(@w)'  This runs fine. The error given seems to be something to do with the s/// part.

Answer (score 7):

This problem seems to be basically the same as a known [rakudo issue for the `race` method](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1950).

I switched from:

```
if $temp ~~ s:g/ (<$pattern>) /$color_red$0$color_off/ {
```

to:

```
if $temp ~~ s:g/ ($pattern) /$color_red$0$color_off/ {
```

and the problem seemed to go away.

As later mentioned by [Xin Cheng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9983580/xin-cheng) and also described in the same doc, the simpler interpolation matches literally as clarified by the doc examples.   The issue ticket fixed the problem with something like:

```
my $reg = regex { <$pattern> };
'' ~~ $reg;
```

leading to an updated program with a similar workaround:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

constant $color_red = "\e[31m";
constant $color_off = "\e[0m";

sub MAIN(Str $pattern, *@filenames){
    my $channel = Channel.new();
    $channel.send($_) for @filenames; # dir();
    $channel.close;
    my @workers;    

    # match seems required for pre-compilation
    '' ~~ (my regex pat_regex { <$pattern> });

    for 1..3 -> $n {
        push @workers, start {
            while (my $file = $channel.poll) {
                do_something(&pat_regex, $file);
            }
        }
    }
    await(@workers);
}

sub do_something(Regex $pat_regex, Str $filename) {
#    say $filename;
    for $filename.IO.lines -> $line  {
        my Str $temp = $line;
        if $temp ~~ s:g/ ($pat_regex) /$color_red$0$color_off/ {
            say $filename ~ ": " ~ $temp;
        }
    }
}
```

My apologies for the earlier proposed explicit `EVAL` solution, about which the best I can say is that my description requested a better solution.

Comment: Same problem as I described above. I get nothing if I say "grep6 'p.*l' *"

Comment: @XinCheng - I have updated my answer in response to your comments.

Comment: Thanks, @mr_ron. I tried it and it worked as expected. I certainly learnt a lot from your response and others. Thanks again.

Comment: @XinCheng - believe that more careful reading of relevant material led to an update with a much more reasonable solution.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again. It seems the precompiling of regex is lazy, so one has to use it once to work in the threads. @mr_ron

Answer (score 5):

Did a bit of playing about the issue seems to be the anonymous regexp you're creating by doing :

```
s:g/ (<$pattern>) /$color_red$0$color_off/
```

If you instead precompile your regex (either in `do_something` or the `MAIN` routine then the errors stop. 
Here's the updated `do_something` version :

```
sub do_something(Str $pattern, Str $filename) {
    my $reg = regex { $pattern };
    for $filename.IO.lines -> $line  {
        my Str $temp = $line;
        if $temp ~~ s:g/ ($reg) /$color_red$0$color_off/ { 
            say $filename ~ ": " ~ $temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it won't crash now. And it works when I say something like "grep6 perl *", but it won't work if I use more complicated regex than alphanumeric symbol. For example, I get nothing when I say "grep6 'p.*l' *". It seems to me, to get it work, one needs <$pattern> like construction, but this, as I know now, is not thread safe.